# Javascript date setMonth does not set month correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript

It looks like Javascript setMonth method does not change month correctly if it was used for 31st.

```
var event = new Date('July 31, 2018 10:48:30');

console.log(event.getMonth());
// output: 6

// Change to previous month
event.setMonth(event.getMonth() - 1);

console.log(event.getMonth());
// expected output: 5 actual output: 6

console.log(event);
```

Does anyone have a better option available to change month and set date of 30th if 31st is not in the month?

Comment: You forcibly want the system to assume the date `June 31, 2018 10:48:30`. It shouldn't let you, right?

Comment: Yes, so I was expecting it to change the date to 30th? Instead it changed the date to 1st.

Comment: I think that'll be too ambiguous for a simple subtractor method. Since both 31st Jul and 30th Jul will result in the same value. However, I am not sure that is the reason for this behavior.

Comment: The reason is that it subtracts the month, lands at `June 31, 2018` and then normalizes the date to `July 1`. Just as `setDate(getDate() + 1)` will somewhen cause going to the next month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have a better option available to change month and set date of 30th if 31st is not in the month?

Just go a day before:

```
var event = new Date('July 31, 2018 10:48:30');

console.log(event.getMonth());

// Change to previous month
var current = event.getMonth();
event.setMonth(current - 1);
if (event.getMonth() === current) {
  event.setDate(event.getDate() - 1);
}

console.log(event.getMonth());
// actual output: 5

console.log(event);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  let previous = event.getMonth();
  while(event.getMonth() === previous)
    event.setDate(event.getDate() - 1);
```

Just go back day by day.